# How do I extract one character from any location in a text file?

Tags: c++, char, fstream

I'm trying to extract 1 character from different positions in a text file, not in sequence.
If I have a text file that says, "Hey how you doing?"
Say I want to extract the 6th character "o", and put it in this_char.

I'm a beginner.

```
myfile >> this_char;  //first character
myfile >> this_char;  //second character
```

.
.

```
myfile.get(this_char); //first character
myfile.get(this_char); //second character
```

.
.

```
myfile[6] >> this_char;  //doesn't work

fstream myfile;
myfile.open("C:/Users/muhname/Desktop/INPUT.txt");
char this_char;
```

Comment: `myfile.seekg(wherever)`

Comment: Thank you.   Of course, it starts counting with zero.  :P

Comment: probably add `myfile.seekg(position-1, std::ios::beg);` unless you want to seek again from new position.

Comment: Don't forget that sometimes an end of line can be two characters and screw up your offset.